# How to pass a variable in PHP/Wordpress from child template to parent

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two Wordpress templates

1. The post header
2. The post content which requires the header

I want to pass a "hideContent" variable from the header in some cases and hide the content if it is set to true.

the-content.php file

```
<div class="header">
    <?php require locate_template("the-header.php"); <?php } ?>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <?php if ($hideContent != true) { ?>
        /* content to hide if flag is set */
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

If I do this, will this affect **only** this single call to the header/content or is will it stay set for subsequent posts/requests?

Thanks!

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`locate_template()` only returns filename ( along with path ) of template with highest priority, which you then include as a regular file.

That means, that unlike `get_template_part()`, any variable shares scope with the parent template file and vice versa, so `$hideContent` will be accessible.

What I suggest you to do additionally is to just correct this part:

`<?php if ($hideContent != true) { ?>`

into

`<?php if ($hideContent != true && isset($hideContent)) { ?>`,

or just always have this variable set.

Also, you can add conditions if it is single post ( `is_single()`, then after to check post type ( `global $post`, `$post->post_type`) etc. with a goal to differ various cases

Comment: Thanks! I just ran into that "isset" issue, much appreciated. 8)